# NavigationBarBarTintColor Set issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have set the NavigationBarBarTintColor whiteColor.
such as

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

but it seems like to display black color on the screen.
what's wrong with it?
I have try many ways to solve this problem, but I can't work it out.

Comment: where you added this

Answer (score 0):

Use your code in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.It is working in my side.